# What settings or scenarios break animations' triggers from firing?

Tags: delphi, animation, firemonkey-fm2

I am trying to animate a checkbox through stylebook by;

- Making a layout and naming it 'ch_style1'
- Adding another layout naming it 'layout' ( Align = Left )

  - Adding a TRectangle ( Align = Left; HitTest = False )
  - Setting fill color to animate through TColorAnimation
  - The TColorAnimation ( Enabled = True; Inverse = True; Trigger = IsMouseOver=true; InverseTrigger = IsMouseOver=false )
- Adding a TText and a TShadowEffect

The problem only shows up in my main application where there are a lot of controls though hidden. Each view can contain up to 30-40 controls. There are no performance issues at all. The style designer IDE even shows the animations on the control but running the application suggests as if the IsMouseOver trigger doesn't fire. I have faced success, only if I do it for controls on a new form.

As its all in the IDE, I can't give any code to help my case, the dfm even sits above 600KB... So please enlighten me with your experiences and any possible areas I may look for the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's an inherent bug in FireMonkey (both the original from XE2 and FM2 from XE3) where the animations fail mid-way. It's not you, it's FireMonkey!